# tailwindcss CLI wont work on github pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

i have a project on my laptop using tailwindcss cli, it goes right on my laptop, but when i upload it to github pages it wont work like it never have css or anything, i allraedy reupload it but still have the same result.
[photos on Github pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56nXZ.jpg)
[photos on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA9dn.jpg)

link github :
https://github.com/dimas-web-dotcom/cloning-web-streaming/

how can i fix it, it almost 2 days now

Comment: [Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) -> TLDR: No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo you included seems to be missing a lot of things that could help us help you. For instance the `package.json` file is missing all the scripts that could point us into the direction of how you are building things for prod vs development. Also, we usually don't commit our `node_modules`.

In any case, the issue seems to be related to the URL of your CSS.
Your HTML file points to the CSS like this `<link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />` but your site is located in a subfolder `example.com/mysite/index.html` and that makes the lookup for the CSS to be made in the root of the domain (`example.com/dist/output.css`) instead of the subfolder (`example.com/mysite/dist/output.css`).

So, changing it to a relative path should do the trick:

```html
<link href="./dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: it work bro, thank you very much.

Comment: you are very welcome. as a hint, when facing such issues, always check in the browser devtools network tab to see if you get a `404 not found` error.

Answer (score 0):

If what Elvis Adomnica said haven't worked with you, yet it should, check those links below.

[TailwindCSS working on local computer but not when deployed to GH-Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76941895/tailwindcss-working-on-local-computer-but-not-when-deployed-to-gh-pages)

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/12024

Comment: it work bro, thanks

Comment: So don't just leave! Mark the answer that made your thing work, whether it's Elvis's or mine. That would really help us both. And you can even upvote for the other. And Yeah! Happy that it worked!